# angularjs interceptor for status code 302 not able to read response header set-cookie

Tags: angularjs, cookies, http-status-code-302, angular-http-interceptors, response-headers

the service/backend is sending me set-cookies in a 302 redirect but i am not able to read the response header which has set-cookies. basically i want to redirect the user to login page and clear the session if Set-Cookie:redirectURL="" and it expires immediately. Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

**I am afraid you can't intercept the 302 status code from JavaScript.**

This is because the status `302` simple means request is not yet fulfilled and server is asking the user agent to initiate a new request for the *Url* specified in **Location** header of redirection response.

This entire redirection process is internal to the user agent and JavaScript code is notified only on completion of the request.

Comment: how do i access the set cookies param in the response headers

Comment: I think server has to take care of setting the cookie appropriately and redirection Url.